# Best way to handle sprites in games with different screens in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Another day, another problem.

I have a sprite which has fields such as `livesRemaining`.

Let's say in the main game screen I fall off and I switch the screen to a "Lives Remaining" screen using the `setScreen` method. My problem is that the `livesRemaing` field is now lost.

My question is what is the best way to handle these "global game variables" which should be transition between screens.

Should I:

1. Create one sprite in the game class and pass this to the different screens?
2. Create a new sprite every screen and keep the "global game variables" in the main Game class?

I'm not sure if there is a best approach to this or if it is just a matter of taste.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cache is good to avoid objects creation/destruction (that are expensive on java due to garbage collector on a "real time" game). It seems that you need a better data structure to handle all the game design to avoid that problems. Your option 1 is the closest approach to be a good one, but it depends on the general design.

Comment: I agree with you on this one. I think Option 1 would make the most sense in terms of performance. It makes more OOP sense to hold these variables in the sprite object too and I have more flexibility with what I'm passing into the screen when changing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a static class which contains a static reference to my game, gamescreen, and game camera.

I you do that, you can have access to any component of your game anywhere.

IE
game.player
Or
gamecamera.unproject()

Answer (score 0):

I found your question very interesting because, I ended up having even problem / doubt. In case I ended up creating an **ECS** (*System of Entities*) system I ended up seeing that passing sprite values ​​to the next screen in addition to memory costs brought with it a bad ECS system practice, so I decided to create global variables for the player, because if you realize the world is rotated on top of the player and it has the importance of storing the information of the player's lives, but one thing I can tell you is that this is very delicate because we can have systems in different ways and just as francogp spoke , it all depends on the design and design patterns you are using.